# Static and stagnation enthalpy / pressure derivation for incompressible flow

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure

I was wondering how one could derive the relationship between static and stagnation pressure in incompressible flow from the relationship between static and stagnation enthalpy.

It should be pretty straightforward, since $\rho$ is constant, however I am unsure of what happens to the internal energy $u$ component from the definition of enthalpy. That is, if:

$$
h_0 = h + \frac{C^2}{2}\\
$$
where $h = u + pv$ and $h_0 = u_0 + p_0v_0$

If we assume incompressible flow, so that $v_0=v=v_{const}$, we get:

$$
(u_0 + p_0 v_{const}) = (u + p v_{const}) + \frac{C^2}{2}
$$

However the relationship between $p_0$ and $p$ is:

$$
p_0 = p + \rho \frac{C^2}{2}
$$

So its obvious how we factor out the specific volume $v_{const}$ but not obvious to me how we 'get rid' of the internal energy terms? Is there a particular assumption which means we can neglect these $u_0$ and $u$ terms?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: For an incompressible fluid, internal energy is a function only of temperature.  So, if the stagnation is isothermal, the internal energies are equal.

Comment: Thanks! So under conditions of isothermal flow, one can get rid of the $u$'s. What about non-isothermal flows? Or isothermal flow implicit in the assumptions for stagnation of pressures?